# hive table match and pick value in a different column

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have an input table as :

```
c_no    acc_no  acc_line_no ref_acc ref_acc_item    bt_no
4           a12          50   39080           40    0
4           a13          10   39080           10    0
4           a14          20   39080           20    0
4           a15          30   39080           21    20
4           a16          40   39080           30    0
4           a17          31                    0    20
```

> Issue:ref_acc_item and bt_no is zero or blank for same c_no ;

resolution:

if ref_item is blank then the value 20 in bt_no needs to be matched with acc_line_no (here line 3 matches 20) and set the ref_acc as in line 3 ref_acc value and ref_acc_item as 20 as in bt_no

> output table :

```
 c_no   acc_no  acc_line_no ref_acc ref_acc_item    bt_no
4           a12          50   39080           40    0
4           a13          10   39080           10    0
4           a14          20   39080           20    0
4           a15          30   39080           21    20
4           a16          40   39080           30    0
4           a17          31   39080           20    20
```

please help me achieve this in Hive. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily with a `if` statement

```
select 
c_no,
acc_no,
acc_line_no,
ref_acc,
if(ref_acc_item = "0" or ref_acc_item = "", bt_no, ref_acc_item ),
bt_no
from yourtable
```